# Trouble Getting LatLng from Google places json array object

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-studio

The Problem I seem to be having is accessing the "deeper level" lat lng values from within the json file.

The Json file is being accessed live from google with this type of link:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?

Here is what a single object/array item looks like in json, including the "top Level" "results".

```
"results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 55.4628609,
               "lng" : -4.6299348
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.46420472989273,
                  "lng" : -4.628674020107278
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 55.46150507010728,
                  "lng" : -4.631373679892723
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "0655ceeeddd83f1a901bcef361b22cbfa951ae73",
         "name" : "GAME",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJM8hBpZ3WiUgRuWc3KhfMJys",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "F97C+42 Ayr, UK",
            "global_code" : "9C7QF97C+42"
         },
         "rating" : 4.2,
         "reference" : "ChIJM8hBpZ3WiUgRuWc3KhfMJys",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "electronics_store", "store", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "120 High St, Ayr"
      },
```

Here is the Method im using to access the json file data after it has been parsed to string.

```
  void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .position(new LatLng(
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("geometry").getDouble(0),
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("geometry").getDouble(1)
                    ))
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry is not an array. JSON that begins with **CURLY BRACE {}** is an object while **BRACKET [ ]** indicates an array. Try this one.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray= object.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject locationObj = jsonObj .getJSONObject("geometry")
                                       .getJSONObject("location");

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        locationObj.getDouble("lat"),
                        locationObj.getDouble("lng")
                ))
        );
    }
```

Hope this helps you clarify difference between JSON array and object, and how to access them. Cheers

Comment: It works in that there are no errors but the markers don't display on the map. Thanks for the description.

Comment: @PyStraw45 then thats a different problem buddy. This post doesnt help us figure out what the problem is

Comment: Fair enough,  I'll  ensure that the latlng are parsing properly and see what I can do from there but thanks anyway.